# Get xml from webservice?

Tags: python, xml, web, service

I'm trying to get a data from [this site](http://degra.wi.pb.edu.pl/rozklady/webservices.php?)

and then use some of it. Sorry for not copy-paste it but it's a long xml. So far I tried to get this data those ways:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
url = "http://degra.wi.pb.edu.pl/rozklady/webservices.php?"
s = urlopen(url)
content = s.read()
```

as `print(content)` looks good, now I would like to get a data from it

```xml
<tabela_rozklad data-aktualizacji="1480583567">
<DZIEN>2</DZIEN>
<GODZ>3</GODZ>
<ILOSC>2</ILOSC>
<TYG>0</TYG>
<ID_NAUCZ>66</ID_NAUCZ>
<ID_SALA>79</ID_SALA>
<ID_PRZ>104</ID_PRZ>
<RODZ>W</RODZ>
<GRUPA>1</GRUPA>
<ID_ST>13</ID_ST>
<SEM>1</SEM>
<ID_SPEC>0</ID_SPEC>
</tabela_rozklad>
```

How can I handle this data to easy use it?

Comment: You parse the XML. Please Google doing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Beautiful soup and capture the tags you want. The code below should get you started!

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://degra.wi.pb.edu.pl/rozklady/webservices.php?"

# secure url content
response = requests.get(url).content
soup = BeautifulSoup(response)

# find each tabela_rozklad
tables = soup.find_all('tabela_rozklad')

# for each tabela_rozklad looks like there is 12 nested corresponding   tags
tags = ['dzien', 'godz', 'ilosc', 'tyg', 'id_naucz', 'id_sala',
    'id_prz', 'rodz', 'grupa', 'id_st', 'sem', 'id_spec']

# initialize empty dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame()

# iterate over each tabela_rozklad and extract each tag and append to pandas dataframe
for table in tables:
    all = map(lambda x: table.find(x).text, tags)
    df = df.append([all])

# insert tags as columns
df.columns = tags

# display first 5 rows of table
df.head()

# and the shape of the data
df.shape # 665 rows, 12 columns

# and now you can get to the information using traditional pandas  functionality

# for instance, count observations by rodz
df.groupby('rodz').count()

# or subset only observations where rodz = J
J = df[df.rodz == 'J']
```

Comment: Thank You this really get me started :>

Comment: This is really nice, now Im trying to make something like 

    J = df[df.rodz == 'J' & df.id_prz == '1'] I guess i miss some method

Comment: Try df[(df.rodz == "J") & (df.id_prez == "1")]

Comment: I don't know why but I can't get data with
    a = df[(df.sem== "1")]
any other column, works fine. So I tried with
    a = df.loc[(df.sem== "1")]
this one doesn't give any errors but still i see results with sem=0 to sem=7 and I wanna see result with only 1.

Comment: Oh, and when I use a=df[(df.sem == "1")] i get this error
File "pandas\index.pyx", line 139, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\index.c:4443)
  File "pandas\index.pyx", line 161, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\index.c:4289)
  File "pandas\src\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 732, in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas\hashtable.c:13733)
  File "pandas\src\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 740, in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas\hashtable.c:13687)
KeyError: False